# Laravel run systemctl --user using process

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, service, systemctl

I'm trying to run some services on a ubuntu server using process() (from Symfony\Component\Process\Process)

```
$process = new Process(['systemctl', '--user', 'start', $serviceName]);
     try {
         $process->mustRun();
     } 
     catch (ProcessFailedException $ex) {
         Log::alert($ex->getMessage());
     }
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
The command "'systemctl' '--user' 'start' 'some_service_name.service'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /

Output:


Error Output:

Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It should be systemctl --user enable service

Comment: @Thomas from my understanding enable is only used if you want the service to keep running even after server restart, while start is used to start the service but once the server restart it won't run.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374348/546023) answer may apply if this code is running through a webserver via a controller, but the code should work if running from a terminal.

Comment: @apokryfos indeed the command works in terminal, but not from the job (I already used "loginctl enable-linger www-data") the problem happens when adding the '--user'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for anyone facing the same problem the argument "--machine=username@.host" was missing.

so the end result should be something like this:

```
$process = new Process(['systemctl', '--machine=USER_HERE@.host', '--user', 'start', $serviceName]);
 try {
     $process->mustRun();
 } 
 catch (ProcessFailedException $ex) {
     Log::alert($ex->getMessage());
 }
```

(replace the USER_HERE with your user)